# Error Undefned index al utilizar ajax

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy tratando de pasar una valor por de ajax a un formulario PHP, pero me dice que tengo un error:

el código que llama a la función PHP es el siguiente:

```html
<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="ID_Nova" id="ID_Nova" placeholder="ID Novedad" required="true" value ="<?php echo $ID_Novedad ?>" readonly ></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="Docu" id="Docu" placeholder="Número de documento" required="true" value ="<?php echo $Documento ?>" readonly ></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="Anoen" id="Anoen" placeholder="Año" required="true" value ="<?php echo $Ano ?>" readonly ></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="Mesen" id="Mesen" placeholder="Mes" required="true" value ="<?php echo $Mes ?>" readonly ></td>  
<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="Peri" id="Peri" placeholder="Período" required="true" value ="<?php echo $periodo ?>" readonly ></td>  
<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="Conce" id="Conce" placeholder="Concepto" required="true" value ="<?php echo $Concepto ?>" readonly ></td>  


<body onload="lista_DescuentoNovedad(ID_Nova.value, Docu.value,Anoen.value,Mesen.value,Peri.value,Conce.value);">
```

La función de ajax es la siguiente:

```html
 function lista_DescuentoNovedad(ID_Novedad,Documento,Ano,Mes,periodo,Concepto){
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();
  var Documento = $('#Docu').val();
  var Ano = $('#Anoen').val();
  var Mes = $('#Mesen').val();
  var periodo = $('#Peri').val();
  var Concepto = $('#Conce').val();
  var datastring ={'ID_Novedad=' + ID_Novedad + '&Documento=' + Documento + '&Ano=' + Ano + '&Mes=' + Mes + '&periodo=' + periodo + '&Concepto=' + Concepto};
          $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(){
             $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html('<b>Actualizando lista de Descuentos en la novedad...</b>');
           },
          url: 'lista_DescuentoNovedad.php',
    data: datastring,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(x){
            $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html(x);
   /********************HAY QUE VALIDAR #lista_clientes*******************************/
            $("#lista_clientes").dataTable();
           },
           error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){}
           });
          });
 }
```

El código PHP donde recibe la información es el siguiente:

```html
<?php
include ("funciones/conex.php");
$link=Conectarse();

$ID_Novedad = $_POST['ID_Novedad'];
$Documento = $_POST['Documento'];
$Ano = $_POST['Ano'];
$Mes = $_POST['Mes'];
$periodo = $_POST['periodo'];
$Concepto = $_POST['Concepto'];
$AnoActual=date("Y");
$con=mysql_query("SELECT D.ID,D.ID_Novedad,D.ID_Dcto,D.ValorDcto,D.Estado,DC.NomDcto FROM tbl_dtldcto as D INNER JOIN tbl_dctos AS DC ON D.ID_Dcto=DC.ID_Dcto where D.ID_Novedad='$ID_Novedad' AND D.Estado = 'PENDIENTE'",$link);

?>
```

Los errores que me arroja el sistema son:

> Notice: Undefined index: Documento in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Abecol\modulos\lista_DescuentoNovedad.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Ano in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Abecol\modulos\lista_DescuentoNovedad.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Mes in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Abecol\modulos\lista_DescuentoNovedad.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: periodo in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Abecol\modulos\lista_DescuentoNovedad.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Concepto in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Abecol\modulos\lista_DescuentoNovedad.php on line 10

El dato ID_Novedad, no tiene ningún inconveniente.

Comment: quita los `{}` de la variable `datastring`

Comment: Hola Albert, gracias por la respuesta , pero al quitar los {} el error se mantiene, es decir que no se ha solucionado el inconveniente aún.

Comment: Me interesa esto, voy a crear un proyecto simulando tu escenario, regreso en breve.

Answer (score 4):

Bien mi solución es la siguiente;

En la parte de tu `Javascript` estas intentando crear un `objeto`, pero esta no es la manera correcta de hacerlo, un objecto posee pares `key` `value` y lo que estas intentando hacer es guardar un `string` dentro de un objecto, la solución es cambiar el `string` a un `objeto`;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();
    var Documento = $('#Docu').val();
    var Ano = $('#Anoen').val();
    var Mes = $('#Mesen').val();
    var periodo = $('#Peri').val();
    var Concepto = $('#Conce').val();
    //Aqui
    var datastring = {
        'ID_Novedad': ID_Novedad,
        'Documento': Documento,
        'Ano': Ano,
        'Mes': Mes,
        'periodo': periodo,
        'Concepto': Concepto
    };

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html(
                '<b>Actualizando lista de Descuentos en la novedad...</b>');
        },
        url: 'lista_DescuentoNovedad.php',
        data: datastring,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (x) {
            $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html(x);
            /********************HAY QUE VALIDAR #lista_clientes*******************************/
            $("#lista_clientes").dataTable();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, estado, error) {}
    });
});
```

Ahora ya puedes acceder a los indices en tu `backend` sin problemas

Comment: Hola Albert, con la solución que me diste ya no sale el error de Undefined index, sin embargo al imprimir las variables en el formulario destino no me trae los datos, me aparece undefined, solo me está trayendo la información de ID

Comment: @JuanCarlos Revisa las mayúsculas y minúsculas en el backend, el front esta bien y según vi tu código coinciden las variables.